# TypeScript cannot find node module with index.d.ts

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I'm trying to use [EventEmmiter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) with the following syntax:

```js
import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'
```

I have this module installed under the `./node_modules` folder. This module contains a [`index.d.ts`](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3/blob/master/index.d.ts) so I think it should be detected by Typescript. But instead get the error:

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'eventemitter3'.
```

I tried adding `./node_modules` to the included types in my `tsconfig.json` without success:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules", "./node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

How should I configure Typescript to find node modules?

Comment: EventEmitter has no default exporter, try to import using `import * as EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3'`

Comment: @rpadovani I ran into this issue as well. With your code I couldn't extend the EventEmitter class which I think is strange.. Though this works: `import {EventEmitter} from 'eventemitter3'`. I guess it's really just a case by case solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it by adding the following in my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "Node"
  }
}
```

[source](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: The reason for this is the fact that for `target: es6` and higher TypeScript by default uses `module: ES6` and therefore `moduleResolution: Classic`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html And classic module resolution doesn't work with `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

For ECMAScript that use `import` statement, set the `moduleResolution` to 'nodenext' instead

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext"   // or 'node16'
  }
}
```